# No audio when DVI to HDMI cable is plugged. How to fix this?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, 15.04

I have been using LG TV as monitor with [Audio Cable](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3223/2875838813_f7c9c2a70b_o.jpg) and [DVI to HDMI cable](http://www.evilbox.ro/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/DVI-I-to-HDMI.jpg)

I am getting audio when VGA cable is plugged. But when the DVI to HDMI cable is plugged I couldn't get audio *(Probably because audio is routed through DVI to HDMI cable instead of audio cable?)*.

alsamixer

```
Card: HDA Intel MID                                          
Chip: Intel IbexPeak HDMI
```

aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```